# Android Studio. не найдены классы

Tags: android-studio

При создании приложения в Android Studio возникают проблемы:
не пишет Hello world (не найдены классы).

Подскажите в чем может быть дело?
[image: rendering problems]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите содержимое вашего файла build.gradle, блок с зависимостями dependencies

Comment: там над экраном телефона есть иконка андроида и цифра 24, поменяйте там на 23 или 22 , нужно что бы цифра была не больше чем у вас в build.gradle targetSdkVersion